# Analyzing string input until it reaches a certain letter on Python

Tags: python, string, input, edit

I need help in trying to write a certain part of a program.
The idea is that a person would input a bunch of gibberish and the program will read it till it reaches an "!" (exclamation mark) so for example:

```
input("Type something: ")
```

*Person types: wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223*

If I ask the program to print the input it should only print `wolfdo65gtornado` and cut anything once it reaches the "!" The rest of the program is analyzing and counting the letters, but those part I already know how to do. I just need help with the first part. I been trying to look through the book but it seems I'm missing something.

I'm thinking, maybe utilizing a `for` loop and then placing restriction on it but I can't figure out how to make the random imputed string input be analyzed for a certain character and then get rid of the rest.

If you could help, I'll truly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

The built-in [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method will do this for you. Unlike [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it won't bother to cut the rest of the `str` into different `str`s.

```
text = raw_input("Type something:")
left_text = text.partition("!")[0]
```

**Explanation**

`str.partition()` returns a 3-tuple containing the beginning, separator, and end of the string. The `[0]` gets the first item which is all you want in this case. Eg.:

```
"wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223".partition("!")
```

returns

```
('wolfdo65gtornado', '!', 'salmontiger223')
```

Comment: Of course it will, the difference is that partition keeps the "!" character (in this case) inside the array (well it actually outputs to a list rather than an array):  

    >>> s.partition('!')
    ('wolfdo65gtornado', '!', 'salmontiger223')
    >>> s.split('!')
    ['wolfdo65gtornado', 'salmontiger223']
    >>>

Comment: I'm saying that if there are multiple `"!"` characters, you won't get a list with the split at every single one of them.

Comment: well, yes you will: `s = "wolfdo!65gtornado!salmo!ntig!er223"`
`s.split('!')` `['wolfdo', '65gtornado', 'salmo', 'ntig', 'er223']` and you won't have to jump every second position in the array if you iteriate over it afterwards, as you would with rpartition

Comment: I'm talking about the case where you use `str.partition()` to do this, not `str.split()`. This is exactly the use case for which `str.partition()` was added to the language.

Comment: well in this particular use case I see no reason to use `str.partition` over `str.split` but please do feel free to enlighten me - is it faster or something?

Comment: i had some type problems so i found that you can also use casting on another type and then do partition() or split()      , maybe someone finds it useful   `str(e).partition(":")[0]) `

Comment: @MichaelHoffman What is that `[0]` at the end? What if I want to take a string from the end of the long string? In the above case it would be `salmontiger223`

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
>>> s.split('!')[0]
'wolfdo65gtornado'
>>> s = "wolfdo65gtornadosalmontiger223"
>>> s.split('!')[0]
'wolfdo65gtornadosalmontiger223'
```

if it doesnt encounter a "**!**" character, it will just grab the entire text though. if you would like to output an error if it doesn't match any "**!**" you can just do like this:

```
s = "something!something"
if "!" in s:
  print "there is a '!' character in the context"
else:
  print "blah, you aren't using it right :("
```

Comment: The `split()` function is not efficient for this application. Suppose that the string is 10,000 characters long. the 53rd character is an exclamation mark `!`. If you read the string from left to right, then we can stop as soon as we encounter the delimiter `!` We only need the beginning (prefix) of the string. The `split()` function will keep going and going.

Answer (score 8):

You want [`itertools.takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

```
>>> s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
>>> '-'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '!', s))
'w-o-l-f-d-o-6-5-g-t-o-r-n-a-d-o'



>>> s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223!cvhegjkh54bgve8r7tg"
>>> i = iter(s)
>>> '-'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '!', i))
'w-o-l-f-d-o-6-5-g-t-o-r-n-a-d-o'
>>> '-'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '!', i))
's-a-l-m-o-n-t-i-g-e-r-2-2-3'
>>> '-'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '!', i))
'c-v-h-e-g-j-k-h-5-4-b-g-v-e-8-r-7-t-g'
```

Comment: i have a variable f_name='file.txt'
using ur valuable idea of itertools.takewhile(),
i tried this
bck_f_name='backup'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == ".",f_name))
with an expectation of getting the bck_f_name as 'filebackup.txt'
but i couldn't achieve this.....any help wud b appreciable

Comment: This solution is ~10x slower than other solutions `.split()` or `.partition()` in terms of performance

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
m = s.index('!')
l = s[:m]
```

Comment: What if there is no `!` in the string? Then an exception, `ValueError`, is raised.

Comment: Surprisingly, this solution is a tiny bit slower than the one with `.partition()`

Answer (score 4):

To explain accepted answer.

**Splitting**

`partition()` function splits string in list with 3 elements:

```
mystring = "123splitABC"
x = mystring.partition("split")
print(x)
```

will give:

`('123', 'split', 'ABC')`

**Access** them like list elements:

`print (x[0])` ==> 123

`print (x[1])` ==> split

`print (x[2])` ==> ABC

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have:

```
s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223" + some_other_string
```

`s.partition("!")[0]` and `s.split("!")[0]` are both a problem if `some_other_string` contains a million strings, each a million characters long, separated by exclamation marks. I recommend the following instead. It's much more efficient.

```
import itertools as itts
get_start_of_string = lambda stryng, last, *, itts=itts:\
                          str(itts.takewhile(lambda ch: ch != last, stryng))
###########################################################
s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
start_of_string = get_start_of_string(s, "!")
```

---

### Why the `itts=itts`

Inside of the body of a function, such as `get_start_of_string`, `itts` is global.
`itts` is evaluated when the function is ***called***, not when the function is ***defined***.
Consider the following example:

```
color = "white"
get_fleece_color = lambda shoop: shoop + ", whose fleece was as " + color + " as snow."

print(get_fleece_color("Igor"))

# [... many lines of code later...]

color = "pink polka-dotted"
print(get_fleece_color("Igor's cousin, 3 times removed"))
```

The output is:

```
Igor, whose fleece was white as snow.
Igor's cousin, 3 times removed Igor, whose fleece was as pink polka-dotted as snow.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the beginning of a string, up until the first delimiter is encountered, by using regular expressions.

```
import re

slash_if_special = lambda ch:\
    "\\" if ch in "\\^$.|?*+()[{" else ""

prefix_slash_if_special = lambda ch, *, _slash=slash_if_special: \
    _slash(ch) + ch

make_pattern_from_char = lambda ch, *, c=prefix_slash_if_special:\
    "^([^" + c(ch) + "]*)"

def get_string_up_untill(x_stryng, x_ch):
    i_stryng = str(x_stryng)
    i_ch = str(x_ch)
    assert(len(i_ch) == 1)
    pattern = make_pattern_from_char(ch)
    m = re.match(pattern, x_stryng)
    return m.groups()[0]
```

An example of the code above being used:

```
s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
result = get_string_up_untill(s, "!")
print(result)
# wolfdo65gtornado
```

Comment: Running the code as written throws an `NameError` at `pattern = make_pattern_from_char(ch)`

Comment: Surprisingly, this bulky-looking solution is only 2x slower than `.partition()`

Answer (score -2):

We can use ***itertools***

```
s = "wolfdo65gtornado!salmontiger223"
result = "".join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x : x!='!' , s))

>>"wolfdo65gtornado"
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as one of the other answers?